# Understanding spsample in R?

Tags: r, interpolation, sampling

I have read the documentation for this but still unsure of what the function spsample does.

The documentation is here:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.3-1/topics/spsample

I came across this while trying to do interpolation on a dataset, referencing this page: https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/interpolation-in-r.html

Just to clarify, is this function trying to split an area of interest using a grid, and trying to put a value for each cell on the grid using the data that we feed into the function? But I am not sure why the idw function would require a grid that has values. I thought the inputs to idw would just be the points we are trying to interpolate.

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `gstat::idw` can predict at any x,y location, but if you want to show that as a continuous map then you need a raster. The example does:

```
# Interpolate the grid cells using a power value of 2 (idp=2.0)
P.idw <- gstat::idw(Precip_in ~ 1, P, newdata=grd, idp=2.0)
```

to predict at a regular grid of x,y coordinates generated by `spsample`

It then converts the output from `idw` to a raster:

```
# Convert to raster object then clip to Texas
r       <- raster(P.idw)
```

then plotting `r` will show it as a continuous raster surface (although its really only a grid of point samples).

Equivalently you could create an empty raster object first, and use `coordinates(r)` to generate a matrix of X,Y coordinates to pass to `idw`, and then put the returned values into the raster.

Comment: so spsample generates a grid of x, y coordinates? Sorry but what is it sampling from and why do we need to sample them? I dont quite get that part. How is it possible to randomly sample coordinates? arent coordinates fixed?

Comment: Its being fed `P` which is a polygon, and `spsample` in this instance is creating a set of grid points within P. spsample can do regular, random or other patterns of points.